# Prove, inequality ,positive numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

$$\frac{a}{e+a+b}+\frac{b}{a+b+c}+\frac{c}{b+c+d}+\frac{d}{c+d+e}+\frac{e}{d+e+a}<2$$

Prove that for positive numbers $a,b,c,d,e$ there is such inequality

Comment: you may add the Inequality tag and also please try to add a bit of what you have tried. Thank you.

Comment: I have it I'll write it here in few seconds

Comment: same to you, thanks

Answer (score 3):

For convenience of notation I'll use $a_i$'s ($1 \le i \le 5$) instead of $a,b,c,d,e$.

Wlog assume $a_1+a_2+a_3 = \min\limits_{1 \le i \le 5}\{a_{i-1}+a_i+a_{i+1}\}$

(where, the indexing is cyclic $a_{0} = a_{5}$ and $a_6 = a_1$ and so on)

Then, $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{i=1}^{3} \frac{a_i}{a_{i-1}+a_i+a_{i+1}} \le \frac{a_1}{a_1+a_2+a_3}+\frac{a_2}{a_1+a_2+a_3}+\frac{a_3}{a_1+a_2+a_3} = 1$

And, $\displaystyle \frac{a_4}{a_3+a_4+a_5}+\frac{a_5}{a_4+a_5+a_1} < \frac{a_4}{a_4+a_5} + \frac{a_5}{a_4+a_5} = 1$.

Adding together we get:

$$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{i=1}^{5} \frac{a_i}{a_{i-1}+a_i+a_{i+1}} < 2$$

Infact using a $5$-tuple, $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5) = (x,y,x,y,x)$ and letting $y \to \infty$,

$$\lim\limits_{y \to \infty} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{5} \frac{a_i}{a_{i-1}+a_i+a_{i+1}} =\lim\limits_{y \to \infty} \frac{3x}{x+2y}+\frac{2y}{2x+y} = 2$$

Hence, $2$ is the best possible upper-bound here.

Comment: why $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{i=1}^{3} \frac{a_i}{a_{i-1}+a_i+a_{i+1}} \le \frac{a_1}{a_1+a_2+a_3}+\frac{a_2}{a_1+a_2+a_3}+\frac{a_3}{a_1+a_2+a_3} = 1$? I'm not familiar with sigma and max notation

Comment: @II irk! sorry $a_1+a_2+a_3 = \min\limits_{1 \le i \le 5}\{a_{i-1}+a_i+a_{i+1}\}$ (edited)

Answer (score 1):

We can write our equation as $\frac{a}{s}+\frac{b}{g}+\frac{c}{r}+\frac{d}{p}+\frac{e}{x}<2$.
 After some operations we get to $s(x(p(br+cg)+d(gr))+egrp)$

and then

$sgrpx(\frac{p(br+cg)+dgr}{grp}-\frac{2grp}{grp})<-agrpx-se$

and again

$s(\frac{pbr+pcg+dgr-2grp}{grp})<-a-\frac{e}{grpx}$

so

$\frac{pbr+pcg+dgr-2grp}{grp}<0$

and

$-2grp<0$

$-2(a+b+c)(b+c+d)(c+d+e)<0$

Comment: you wrote $s(\frac{pbr+pcg+dgr-2grp}{grp})<-a-\frac{e}{grpx}$, after that you seem to have divided by $pbr+pcg+dgr-2grp$ and kept the direction of inequality as is, which is possible only if $pbr+pcg+dgr-2grp > 0$ (I guess you did it the other way round)

Comment: yes you are right, thanks for remark

Comment: I'll try and write my solution :)